# how to multiple two table values in another table in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have tried to multiply two values from different tables in another table. (Please see the picture below). However I have received #VALUE. Do you know why it is not working?

I used this formula:

```
   =Table5[@Income]*Table4[@Income]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it will only work when oriented like this

[image]

The data has to be on the same actual row as the formula, not just the same row relative to the top of the table.